# " d'où qu'il vienne" = "from anywhere"?

Tags: sens, traduction

Here is some rules text from a Magic: the Gathering card (MtG is a collectible card game) called ["Enlèvement par les lanternes"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=541854):

> Si l'Enlèvement par les lanternes devait être mis dans un cimetière
> **d'où qu'il vienne**, exilez-le à la place.

The English language version (called "Lanterns' Lift") has the following rules text:

> If Lanterns' Lift would be put into a graveyard **from anywhere**,
> exile it instead.

The DeepL translation of the French version I quoted above is:

> If the Removal by Lanterns were to be put in a cemetery **from wherever
> it came from**, exile it instead.

The DeepL translation seems quite useless: "from whenever it came from" seems to give no clarifying meaning:

- That is "If [this card] would be put into a graveyard from wherever it came from" seems to mean exactly the same as: "If [this card] would be put into a graveyard".
- In contrast, he English's "from anywhere" serves to *clarify* or *empahize* that it doesn't matter where the card came from before it was put into a graveyard.

(Normally in this card game, typically rules text only cares about when cards are put into the graveyard from "the battefield", even though cards can also be put into the graveyard from "a player's hand" or "a player's library" or "the stack"; so this clarification "from anywhere" makes sense to write out explicitly).

QUESTION:

1. Why was "d'où qu'il vienne" chosen to translate "from anywhere", instead of "de n'import où"?
2. Despite "from wherever it came from" not having any clarifying meaning in English, does "d'où qu'il vienne" have a clarifying meaning for French speakers?

Comment: I just clicked on your link. Those cards on the page are a mixture of French text and English text. None of the text makes much sense. Asking about "d'où qu'il vient" is one thing but in that sentence the antecedent is graveyard, which makes no sense. I don't understand how Hasbro creates or maintains these texts because they are awful. Truly awful. Also, these terms enlèvement and lift are not translations of each other at all and also make no sense.

Comment: For example: If Lanterns' Lift would be put into a graveyard from anywhere, exile it instead. should be: were put. Bur that's not the worst of it....

Comment: @Lambie I suppose I've been playing the game so long, that the English makes perfect sense to me and doesn't sound awkward at all! I'm trying to see how the English sounds strange or incomprehensible for someone who's never played the game before, but I can't -- I'm literally blind to being able to see the text as if I never played the game before..! (e.g. "Are you making dinner, honey? If you **would put** meat in the soup as usual, **instead** don't do that. I invited my vegetarian friends over tonight" sounds fine to me?)

Comment: Ok, well, here, this might help you: It isn't, if you would put meat in the soup.  **If you put or were to put meat in the soup, it would** taste better**". The *would* does not go in the IF clause. You have repeated this misplacement of *would* in several places., I saw some other weird stuff on the cards too but can't remember the sentence without looking at the link. The DeepL translation also **makes this mistake**.

Comment: If you put meat in the soup, please take it out. No would.

Comment: @Lambie I think you misjudge a litte bit those cards. Though the texts are somewhat awkard due to their strange game-specific syntax, the titles are often quite poetic. [Lift has a lot meanings in english](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lift?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) : act of lifting, raising, or stealing. Can you find a translation that encompass all those meanings? *Enlever* has the connotation of *lifting* and *stealing*. What would have been better? Levage? ascension? Elévation? Dérobade?

Comment: @XouDo enlèvement is removal or kidnapping or abduction. Anyway, my issue was about the If clause of the sentence. That said, to use something to lift someone into the air should be: **soulèvement par les lanternes**, not enlèvement. If we are translating into French from English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acknowledging the comments about the questionable grammar in that context, we can still learn something something about the particular phrase « d'où qu'il vienne ».

We can state the rule thus: a question pronoun plus *que* means "____ever", which we could also translate "any ____" or "no matter ____" depending on the context.

| Question | Formula | ____ever | Any ____ | No matter ____ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Où | Où que ce soit | Wherever it is | Anywhere | No matter where |
| D'où | D'où que cela vienne | Wherever it's from | From anywhere | No matter where from |
| Quoi | Quoi que ce soit | Whatever it is | Anything | No matter what |
| Quel | Quel qu'il soit | What/whoever it is | Anything / any one | No matter what/who |
| Qui | Qui que ce soit | Whoever it is | Anyone | No matter who |

(Also see Personne's note re: Quel qu'il soit vs. Quel que soit ____)

However, some question words don't seem to work here and have to be paraphrased. I notice that English "____ever" doesn't work well with this set either, for whatever reason (!).

| Question | Formula | Any ____ | No matter ____ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pourquoi | Pour quelque raison que ce soit | For any reason | No matter the reason |
| Quand | Quelle que soit l'heure / la date | At any time | No matter the time |
| Comment | Quelle que soit la manière | In any way | No matter how |
| Combien | Quel que soit le montant | Any amount | No matter how much |

... This formula can be used with the first table, too: "quel/quelle/quels que soit l'endroit, l'origine, la chose, la personne, etc." but it feels less elegant to me.

Hopefully this observation generally holds up. I invite correction if I've mischaracterized it.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that this is likely to clarify completely my confusions. also clarifies the "Quoi que ce soit" that i often see, but couldn't find explained in my usual grammar websites. thanks! i still have to think about the difference between "D'où que ce vienne" and "De n'importe où", but i can ask another question if i can't figure that out.

Comment: @silph Glad it helps. Because you mentioned how often it comes up in the wild, I'll add a third column to the first table with a common meaning (which you've probably already deduced)

Comment: "No matter where it is from". I just don't see why no one clicked on the link to see the "cards". The French and English are so bad.....So, it is a waste of time since the antecedent in the card is clearly the cemetery, and the phrase makes zero sense there.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, both original texts are pretty bad, but the phrase « d'où qu'il soit » and those like it analyzed independently are still useful to learn, I think.

Comment: Yes, it just I would have put a great, big caveat at the beginning to avoid all the back and forth. :)

Answer (score 2):

**1** - The sentence you quote:

> *Si l'Enlèvement par les lanternes devait être mis dans un cimetière, d'où qu'il vienne, exilez-le à la place.*

is just not proper French. There are no mistakes as such but a French person would not express it like that.
We may look at alternate possibilities, and they are not exclusive of each other. First, I'm 99 %<sup>1</sup> sure the French text was translated, and most probably automatically translated, or by someone not very good at French. The English and German texts don't sound better.
I don't know the game and I couldn't find in what language it was created but during my search I [came upon a forum](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/552313-solved-if-a-card-would-be-put-into-a-graveyard) that makes me think "from anywhere" is a concept in the game, and/or the name of a zone<sup>2</sup>. If the game has been translated into French and *d'où qu'il vienne* is the standard translation of the concept, it seems logical the same name is kept for it throughout the game. And in this case you must see it as you would see the name of a country or a town; if we had "France" (or whatever place) instead of *où qu'il vienne*, this part of the sentence would make perfect sense.

**2-** DeepL's translation you give (I did not get the same when I tried it!) is correct (except from a "from" in excess) if we consider "from anywhere" is not a concept, and how would DeepL know it is a concept? Machines only know what they have been taught and [DeepL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepL_Translator) has not been meant and trained to translate card games. It's the best translation it could give according to what little context the sentence gives.

**3-** Here are a few sentences where *d'où qu'il vienne* is used, it cannot always be translated by "from anywhere":

- *Tout professionnel de santé d’où qu’il vienne est le bienvenu* ([L'est républicain](https://www.estrepublicain.fr/sante/2021/11/11/tout-professionnel-de-sante-d-ou-qu-il-vienne-est-le-bienvenu)) (Any health professional from anywhere is welcome, my translation).
- *Le racisme, d'où qu'il vienne, est un crime du cœur et de l'esprit* (Jaques Chirac) (Racism, wherever it comes from, is a crime of the heart and mind, my translation).
- *La violence, d'où qu'elle vienne et qui qu'elle vise, est inacceptable* ([Parlement du Canada](https://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/36-1/SJCA/reunion-33/temoignages)) (Violence from anyone and used on anyone is unacceptable and deplorable, translation on the same website).

**4-** Not taking into account the rest of the sentence in the card game, and so exclusive of any context, I would never say *un cimetière d'où qu'il vienne* because *un cimetière* cannot *venir*, it is firmly set in the ground and no movement can be involved. I would say something like: *un cimetière, où qu'il soit situé*.

---

Edit after comments exchanged with OP.
Now that I've been explained a little more what the game is about the sentence would make more sense like that :

> D'où qu'il vienne, si l'Enlèvement par les lanternes devait être mis dans un cimetière,  exilez-le (la) plutôt.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> 1 % allowed for the fact that I don't speak "games" whatever the language, and I might just be ignorant of a whole semantic field in English and in French.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> This looks like a definition of the concept, and "from anywhere" is between brackets: "The "from anywhere" part of the ability means that it doesn't care what zone it came from... ".</sup>

Comment: i suspect that my poor French language understanding, plus your lack of knowledge of the game (not your fault!) makes your response difficult for me to understand -- but thank you for making your response, anyways! the game is originally created in English, and "Whenever [cardname] is put into a graveyard from anywhere" makes perfect sense to my native-English ears. "From anywhere" is not a specific concept in the game. "From anywhere" could be written more precisely as "from any zone", though. I'm not sure if these remarks of mine help clarify details for you, but there they are!

Comment: From your response, it seems that " d'où qu'il vienne" is an expression. That is, it does not mean what it literally says (ie, "from where it came" is what it literally says, but the expression means closer to "from anywhere" or "where-ever it comes from"). I didn't realize it was an expression, because WReference didn't have any results for "où qu'il vienne"!

Comment: Finally, it is not the graveyard that can *venir*, but instead a card. "If [cardname] would be *put into* a graveyard *from* anywhere" means that in the game, it's typical that a *card* gets moved *from* some zone [typically a zone called "the battlefield"],  *into* the zone called "[a certain player's] graveyard". (But now i worry that i only confused you more with this technical talk! And obviously, it's very possible that I misunderstood what you're trying to explain to me)

Comment: @silph *D'où qu'il vienne* is not an expression. Here we have a typical translator's case where preposition &/or adverbs (invariable words) can only be translated by a verb group. "from anywhere" did indeed sound like a concept on the forum I mention and  it seems to be used throughout the game, so in spite of my non existing knowledge of the game, if is is a constant in the game it needs one translation to be adopted.

Comment: @silph If from what you say *l'Enlèvement par les lanternes* is the name of the card and it is the card that is supposed to come from anywhere then the French sentence should read *Si  l'Enlèvement par les lanternes,  d'où qu'il/elle vienne, devait être mis dans un cimetière, exilez-le/la à la place*  which makes a lot more sense. You also have the problem of  *le* or *la* whether you consider the card is a masculine concept or ... a card, *une carte* and therefore feminine.

Comment: @silph Have I got it right: *l'Enlèvement par les lanternes* is the name of the card,  in case we have to put the card in a cemetery,  we mustn't do that but exile it instead. The translation I just added to the answer is along this understanding.  *à la place* is not a good translation for "instead" here (it could be in another sentence). Still I don't know enough of the game to choose between *elle* or *il* for the card.  I'll delete whatever part of my answer is superfluous. I started writing a comment for enlightenment but it got too long. The question really needed "more details".

Comment: you understand it correctly in your most recent comment (ie, about the card being exiled instead of being put into the cemetery)! i'm still confused (and interested) about how *D'où qu'il vienne* as not being an expression. It still seems to be literally translated as "From where it comes", but from your example sentences, it doesn't mean that literal translation, but instead means something like "From wher**ever** it comes" or "From who**ever** it comes"? One confusion might be some nuance between "where" and "wherever" in English that (maybe?) doesn't exist in French? i'll have to think more

Comment: Would you be willing to add to your answer, a response to my question of: is is correct to say "Si [cardname] devai être mis dans un cimetière **de n'importe où**"?

Comment: @silph Have you seen my edit? 28 min ago, or do you want more...  French doesn't have the equivalent of where/when/what/who/ever, we have to say sth  like *quelque soit ...* but this is getting too long and might be another question? *D'où qu'il/elle vienne* can be a good way getting around it.

Comment: i did indeed see your edit! weirdly, i believe M:tg cards use "la" if the character on the card's art look feminine, and "le" if the character looks masculine! i do see that you made a suggested translation of the rules text, and that translation makes sense to me. but i still am confused about how "D'où qu'il vienne" is not an expression, which suggests that there's something about the grammar (or semantics) of that phrase that I don't understand.

Comment: oh -- i just saw your updated (edited) comment! i'll probably have to think about where my confusion about "where" vs "wherever" is coming from, and post another question. still, you might be able to answer my question (if you're willing) about if *"Si l'Enlèvement par les lanternes devait être mis, **de n'importe où**, dans un cimetière, exilez-le (la) plutôt."* is correct?

Comment: Yesn I think it might make sense, I would not put the comma after *où* though "*mis de n'importe où dans un cimetière, exilez-le...* " That is if I understand properly that [card] is supposed to end up in a cemetery after coming from anywhere...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about the technicalities of this card game; it makes answering the question more difficult! The rules text is tryinig to say that: that if [card] **would** go *from* any zone *into* the cemetary zone, then don't actually put it into the cemetary zone. **instead**, put that card into the exile zone.

Comment: So the card doesn't actually end up in the cemetary; it instead ends up in the exile zone. (You, of course, had no way of knowing that "exile that card" meant "put that card into the exile zone). I don't know if this technical clarification is relevant or not, but I thought to give it to you anyways.

Comment: Maybe I am confused about the what *D'où qu'il vienne* means (or the different meanings it could take!), and how it is different from *de n'importe où*.

Comment: @silph *Ça peut venir de n'importe où* →It can come from anywhere.  *D'où que ça vienne* →wherever it comes from. Does it help?

Comment: It probbaly helps! I'll have to think about it more when I'm more awake, and then probably try to precisely narrow down where my confusion is, and then ask a fresh question. (I have to clarify to myself: what does "from anywhere" even mean in English, and when would I use "from anywhere" in English?) Thanks for your input so far; it gives me things to try to think about!

Comment: Je ne vois pas bien en quoi cette phrase n'est pas du "proper french"? Il s'agit certes d'un langage plus technique que littéraire (besoin de non-ambigüité pour le jeu).  Pour ma part, je suis presque sûr que ces cartes ne sont pas des traductions automatiques (justement à cause de problème que ça pourrait poser pour le jeu).

Comment: @XouDo Pour  qui ne connait pas le jeu c'est du charabia (mais corect comme je l'ai dit aussi) et je disais clairement que je me plaçais de ce point de vue, donc hors du jeu,  l'OP n'ayant pas donné assez d'explication dans la question. Les explications sont venues après. Restait une question de syntaxe (qui continue à me faire dire que c'est soit une traduction automatique soir une mauvaise maitrise du français) pour que ce soit clair.

Comment: @XouDo  Au cas où tu veuilles « évaluer » la réponse du point de vue de mon appréciation de la phrase de la question il te faudrait partir de l'edit fait après les explications du PO. Le reste est « hors réponse » comme il est dit dans mon commentaire : " I'll delete whatever part of my answer is superfluous", j'attends qu'il me le dise...

Comment: Neither in English or French does d'où qu'il vienne (wherever it comes from r wherever it is from) make sense. The English is bosh and so is the French.

Comment: @Lambie I did write "The English and German texts don't sound better", so I agree with you, don't I?

Comment: @None Yes, absolutely, but I would have placed that at the very beginning of my answer. It's possible that the entire thing refers to the creature enchantée, d'où qu'elle vienne. Otherwise, I don't get it.

Comment: @Lambie It's the 1st § ! Do you agreee when so says "Je ne vois pas bien en quoi cette phrase n'est pas du "proper french"?"

Comment: Yes, and it is incorrect French and incorrect English, both of which appear together in two cards. The texts on each card have half English, half French, none of which make any sense at all. I think this type of junk needs to be called out so Hasbro fixes this type of thing.

Comment: @Lambie So I gather you're not the one who downvoted my answer!

Comment: No, of course not. It was not me.